# Website on mobile: Focus on container instead of whole body?

Tags: responsive-design, focus, zooming

I've really got no clue how to describe the subject in English, so here is more info:

Check my (temporary) website on your phone (no matter what kind one) -> [Click](http://iscs.nl)
What you'll see is the whole site *including the background* spread over your screen, instead of focussing on just the container in particular.

My only question is: How do I let the screen focus on the container, instead of the whole site. By other words: Ignore the background and spread the container over your whole screen.

Quick mockup: [image]

What is the best way to achieve it, so it adjusts it to the whole screen of your phone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

This will "zoom" your device to a reasonable value. ("reasonable" still depends somewhat on the vendor.)

In your case you can play around with `device-width` parameter and enter a value which suits you. But better stick with it for the time being.

Starting from this you can create different css styles via media-query and e.g. specify

```
@media (max-width: 400px)
    .my-content-div {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

to scale your content to 100% on mobile devices.

Making a true responsive design is still a big mess but it can be done. Key is, that you start with something you can at least loosely rely on and then work your way from there.

Comment: Thanks already! 

But, the second piece of code (@media), doesn't that adjusts the size of the the div(creating different size, than stated in the main style.css) (the one instead of '.my-content-div'), instead of 'zooming'/focussing on the main div?

By other words: If the main css stated '.my-content-div' is 'Width:800px;', then by using the @media piece of code, using content="width=device-width", or doesn't that alters the div width size?

Thanks!

Comment: ? Added some more text. What you essentially do in responsive design is change your css for different devices. This is what the media-query here does. This can be pretty radical if needed.

Comment: Another note: `width=device-width` is interpreted by different devices fundamentally differently. But it acts as a kind of browser-hint which tells the mobile browser essentially that you know what you are doing. (I know, this explanation sucks. -- But so do the mobile browsers.)

Comment: check out this (non profit) website I built where I tried to use media queries for responsiveness. This is a good startingpoint because it has only one small css file but many responsive "modes": https://www.binary-kitchen.de/test/blog

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it responsive I think the best solution is by using Media Query instead of adjusting the viewport. Set #container to 100% width and height and set the margin to 0.